# Is a side comment on an opinion off topic?

Tags: discussion

I wrote the following OP : [Does Nash's theorem allow an embedded representation of the Riemann tensor without loss of generality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014330/does-nashs-theorem-allow-an-embedded-representation-of-the-riemann-tensor-witho), which did not receive many views, comments or votes, so I assumed that it was a written outside the topic guidlines for stackexchange. I did mention a side comment on my opinion about the subject in question, but I was not sure if that makes the OP off topic. Is a side comment on an opinion off topic? Should I delete the question? Thanks.

Comment: No, that remark is okay, doesn't make the question off-topic in the least, I'd say. I can imagine your question would have more views, maybe even an answer, if you included more tags (appropriate ones, of course; I guess [tag:differential-geometry] would be suitable and maybe has more followers than [tag:riemannian-geometry]).

Comment: If the question was outside the topic guidelines, it probably would have been put on hold. I don't think its being off topic follows from a low number of views, comments, or votes.